# Different behavior in C and java through JNA

Tags: java, c, jna

I'm attempting to access a scanner from java using JNA (or BridJ, the result is the same). When making calls to the dll from C, the scanner responds correctly to the open (open communication with the scanner), scan and close (close session with the scanner) commands. When I attempt the same code in Java, the call to open() responds with a -3 status code, meaning that the scanner could not be found. This is the same result you get if you turn off or disconnect the scanner when calling from C.

The simplest code for the error is just calling open, and checking whether it was successful. The declaration for the open method in the C header is as follows:

```
extern int APIENTRY LS100_Open(HWND hWnd, HANDLE Hinst, char Type_com);
```

My java interface for the dll is:

```
public interface LS100 extends StdCallLibrary {
public LS100 instance = (LS100)Native.loadLibrary("Ls100", LS100.class);

    public final static byte SUSPENSIVE_MODE = 'S';
    public final static byte NOT_SUSPENSIVE_MODE = 'T';
    public int LS100_Open(HWND hWnd, HANDLE Hinst, byte Type_com);
}
```

My main method for now simply calls `LS100.LS100_Open(null, null, LS100.SUSPENSIVE_MODE)`. Null handles work fine in C (using NULL).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible that your C program and JNA are pulling in dependent libraries from different locations and getting differing versions.

Comment: I checked the dependencies for the program. All dlls that are directly related to the scanner are in the same directory as the one I am calling, and only there. There are some dependencies to Windows dlls, which I suppose get loaded from the same place. Is there a way to determine which dlls are loaded with JNA during a call?

Comment: [procexp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) or profile with [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: I had already checked that all dlls were present. I'll try with procexp and/or procmon to see if they're the **same** as the ones used with C and report later. Thanks!

Comment: I used procexp to determine which libraries the java and C version were using. The C version loads a few libraries that are direct dependencies of the dll I'm trying to use, that were not loaded by the java version. I explicitly made a call to System.loadLibrary() for each of the libraries that were missing, plus I set up the PATH variable to allow java to find the libraries. After setting all of this up, I got the exact same status code as if I had changed nothing. As far as I can tell, every dll needed as reported by dependency walker is in a directory that is in the PATH.